# How to edit multiple file names at once?

Tags: linux, r, filenames

I have directory full of .txt files (2000 files). they have very long name. I want to edit their name and just keep certain letter from inside of their name as file name.
like this :

```
UNCID_279113.TCGA-A6-2683-01A-01R-0821-07.100902_UNC7-RDR3001641_00025_FC_62EPOAAXX.1.trimmed.annotated.gene.quantification.txt
```

I want eliminate this long names and just keep the name starting from `TCGA` and ending after three `-` ; for example, my new file name would be : `TCGA-A6-2683-01A` 
does anybody knows how can I do this for whole files in one directory?

Comment: You could make a shell script with a `for` loop using e.g. `awk` and/or [rename(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the files are in the current directory:

```
library(gsubfn)

pat <- "TCGA-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*"
file.names <- dir(pattern = pat)
new.names <- strapplyc(file.names, pat, simplify = TRUE)
file.rename(file.names, new.names)
```

**Create a shell/batch script** Here is a variation.  It produces a UNIX shell file or a Windows batch file.  You can then review the file and run it:

```
# UNIX
writeLines(paste("mv", file.names, new.names), con = "tcga_rename.sh")
shell("tcga_rename.sh")
```

or on Windows:

```
# Windows
writeLines(paste("rename", file.names, new.names), con = "tcga_rename.bat")
shell("tcga_rename.bat")
```

REVISED: Factored out `pat`, simplified and added variations.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your files are in the current working directory, try

```
library(stringr)

files <- list.files(".", pattern=".txt")
file.rename(files, str_extract(files, "TCGA(-\\w+){3}"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
pattern <- ".*(TCGA-[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]*).*"
file.rename(
  list.files("."),
  sub(pattern, "\\1", list.files("."))
)
```

But be super careful that the `sub` command does what you think it will do before you run the full thing (i.e. just run the `sub` piece).  Hard to be sure this won't cause a problem without knowing what patterns you have in your file names.

Also, in this case replace `list.files(".")` with your directory.  Note you don't need to filter our the files that match the pattern in the first place since `sub` will only modify the file names that do match the pattern (not super efficient if you have a lot of files that don't match the pattern, but easier to write, if a concern, you can use the `pattern` argument as Greg Snow does).

Answer (score 1):

You cane use `list.files()` to get a list of the filenames in the directory, then use substitute with regular expressions to edit the names, then `file.rename` to actually do the renaming.

Something like (untested):

```
curfiles <- list.files(pattern='TCGA') # only grab files with TCGA in them
newfiles <- sub("^.*(TCGA-[a-zA-z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+).*$", "\\1", curfiles)
file.rename(curfiles,newfiles)
```